# Python: Unexpected print output with ANSI color codes and end=""

Tags: python, printing, colors, output, ansi-escape

I'm fairly new to coding and started learning python with "Automate the boring stuff". On trying to create the "Conway's Game of life" (Chapter 4) I tried to highlight the printed output with ANSI color codes to make it visually easier to follow.

I encountered a problem with the following lines:

```
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            print ("\033[1;32;40m" + current_field[y][x] + "\033[1;37;40m", end ="")
        print ("")
```

It should create a square filled with colored 0 and 1's but the output looks something like this (cutout from output):

```
37,40m0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
1;32;40m0 1 1                                                   1 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 
,40m1 0 0
```

On **VS-Code Terminal**
the color itself (green) is working as intended. Mixed with the intended output are random empty spaces, parts of the ANSI codes themselves and seemingly random new lines (without any clear logic I can follow).

On my **current Python Terminal (3.8.3)** it prints out the whole ANSI code along the rest that it should print, but without the green color like this:

```
?[1;32;40m1 ?[1;37,40m??[1;32;40m1 ?[1;37,40m??[1;32;40m1 ?[1;37,40m?
```

If i remove the ANSI codes it works like intended; same goes if i shorten the loop or remove the
end=" " part (but only in VS-Code Terminal - The "regular" python terminal still shows the ANSI codes themselves)

My Questions: I'm trying to understand why this isn't working as intended and how i can "fix" it (while still using the ANSI code - i'm aware of other possibilities to colour printed text such as colorama). Is the problem due to the code or the applications I'm using? (VS-Code with Code Runner and Python Extension / Python Terminal; both on Windows 10; both on Version 3.8.3). Also, why does the VS-Code Python Terminal seem to accept ANSI code and the regular one doesn't?

Comment: Have you tried using the [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) module?

Comment: I'm aware that it exists as i mentioned (Although i have not tried it out yet), but my intention with this post was to understand why my code does not work (or more generally why the ANSI codes do not work like i think they would).

Comment: Ah apologies. In windows ANSI escape codes aren't supported by default I don't think, hence why I'd recommend colorama. As they say in their docs "Colorama makes this work on Windows, too, by wrapping stdout, stripping ANSI sequences it finds (which would appear as gobbledygook in the output), and converting them into the appropriate win32 calls to modify the state of the terminal."

Comment: Ah ok, i should definetly try working with colorama then if I try to use color.

Although besides that, is there a simple reason as to why ANSI codes work on some occations (especially if the print statement is written "Simple" - without any loops or other attachments apart from a single string)?
(I'm trying to tackle/understand most problems i encounter while learning Python, though i know that some things are better left for later to understand)

Comment: I'm not too sure personally, I would just put it down to the fact that it's not supported, so when more complex things are going to stdout it's getting all messed up, especially in the windows terminal as opposed to the VSCode terminal.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the quick answer!